# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to randomly draw out 52 elements and place them in a table consisting of eight groups of six and one group of five. The elements in the array are the elements in question I want to be placed in the table. - http://jsfiddle.net/m5WF7/

There are a number of rules, but I would rather get the code working fully before I implement these rules:

Groups A–H each contains one team from each of Pots 1–6, while Group I contains one team from each of Pots 1–5. - If all cells are filled this rule is obeyed.

For television rights reasons, England, Germany, Italy, Spain and the Netherlands shall be drawn into groups of 6 teams.

For political reasons, Azerbaijan and Armenia (due to disputed status of Nagorno-Karabakh), as well as Spain and Gibraltar (due to disputed status of Gibraltar) shall not be drawn in the same group.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Sample Page that Writes Out an HTML Table</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">
var seed;
var potnum;

var pot1 = ["Spain", "Germany", "Netherlands", "Italy", "England", "Portugal", "Greece", "Russia", "Bosnia"];
var pot2 = ["Ukraine", "Croatia", "Sweden", "Denmark", "Switzerland", "Belgium", "Czech Republic", "Hungary", "Republic of Ireland"];
var pot3 = ['Serbia', 'Turkey', 'Slovenia', 'Israel', 'Norway', 'Slovakia', 'Romania', 'Austria', 'Poland'];
var pot4 = ['Montenegro', 'Armenia', 'Scotland', 'Finland', 'Latvia', 'Wales', 'Bulgaria', 'Estonia', 'Belarus'];
var pot5 = ['Iceland', 'Northern Ireland', 'Albania', 'Lithuania', 'Moldova', 'Macedonia', 'Azerbaijan', 'Georgia', 'Cyprus'];
var pot6 = ['Luxembourg', 'Kazakhstan', 'Liechtenstein', 'Faroe Islands', 'Malta', 'Andorra', 'San Marino', 'Gibraltar'];


var pots = [ 0, pot1 , pot2 , pot3 , pot4 , pot5 , pot6 ];

function sortpot( potnum )
{
    var pot = pots[potnum];
var len = pot.length;
    var rand = Math.random() * (pot.length);
    rand = Math.floor(rand);
    seed = pot[rand];
    console.log(seed);
    pot.splice(rand, 1);
    pots[potnum] = pot;
    return seed;
}





function add2table(potnum, seed) {
var pot = pots[potnum];
return pot[seed]; 
}

document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">')

for(i = 1; i < 7; i++){
document.write('<tr>')
sortpot(i)
   document.write('<td>' + i + '. </td>')
   document.write('<td>' + i + '.' + add2table(i, 1) + '</td>')
   document.write('<td>' + i + '.' + add2table(i, 2) +'</td>')
   document.write('<td>' + i + '.' + add2table(i, 3) +'</td>')
   document.write('<td>' + i + '.' + add2table(i, 4) +'</td>')
   document.write('<td>' + i + '.' + add2table(i, 5) +'</td>')
   document.write('<td>' + i + '.' + add2table(i, 6) +'</td>')
   document.write('<td>' + i + '.' + add2table(i, 7) +'</td>')
   document.write('<td>' + i + '.' + add2table(i, 8) +'</td>')
   if(i < 6) {
   document.write('<td>' + i + '.' + add2table(i, 9) +'</td>')
}
}


document.write('</tr>')



document.write('</table>')



</SCRIPT>
 <button onclick="sortpot(1);">sort Pot 1</button>
 <button onclick="sortpot(2);">sort Pot 2</button>
 <button onclick="sortpot(3);">sort Pot 3</button>
 <button onclick="sortpot(4);">sort Pot 4</button>
 <button onclick="sortpot(5);">sort Pot 5</button>
 <button onclick="sortpot(6);">sort Pot 6</button>
</BODY>
</HTML
```

At the moment I am getting a table with the teams in the arrays filling the columns with the exception of the final two columns and cell 6 of column 7, this probably because of the the Uncaught TypeError. How would I complete the entire table?

I was intending to use the buttons to active to code, but the code executes when I open the Fiddle or web page. I am just looking to fill all cells with teams for now.

Comment: What line of code is the `TypeError` on?

Comment: I don't get any error? http://jsfiddle.net/F2aDS/

Comment: Line 24 - var len = pot.length;

Comment: There's a heck of a lot about your code that bothers me. ALLCAPS HTML TAGS, document.write everywhere, "i" possibly being defined globally, and various other, personal-preference things.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a complete noob at this. I was getting error message but I am no longer. The problem about undefined columns is still evident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still difficult to understand exactly what you are trying to do, but I made a fiddle that will take your list of countries and will generate a random list of the countries from the appropriate pot upon click and put it in a row in a table.  Hope it helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/rKCKX/

HTML:

```
 <button onclick="sortpot(1);">sort Pot 1</button>
 <button onclick="sortpot(2);">sort Pot 2</button>
 <button onclick="sortpot(3);">sort Pot 3</button>
 <button onclick="sortpot(4);">sort Pot 4</button>
 <button onclick="sortpot(5);">sort Pot 5</button>
 <button onclick="sortpot(6);">sort Pot 6</button>

<table id="myTable" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
</table>
```

JS:

```
var countryCollection = [
    ["Spain", "Germany", "Netherlands", "Italy", "England", "Portugal", "Greece", "Russia", "Bosnia"],
    ["Ukraine", "Croatia", "Sweden", "Denmark", "Switzerland", "Belgium", "Czech Republic", "Hungary", "Republic of Ireland"],
    ['Serbia', 'Turkey', 'Slovenia', 'Israel', 'Norway', 'Slovakia', 'Romania', 'Austria', 'Poland'],
    ['Montenegro', 'Armenia', 'Scotland', 'Finland', 'Latvia', 'Wales', 'Bulgaria', 'Estonia', 'Belarus'],
    ['Iceland', 'Northern Ireland', 'Albania', 'Lithuania', 'Moldova', 'Macedonia', 'Azerbaijan', 'Georgia', 'Cyprus'],
    ['Luxembourg', 'Kazakhstan', 'Liechtenstein', 'Faroe Islands', 'Malta', 'Andorra', 'San Marino', 'Gibraltar']
];

function sortpot(listNum){
    var numCountries = countryCollection[listNum-1].length,//cache it because it will change as we splice it
        i,
        randomizedList = [],
        randNum;

    for(i = 0; i < numCountries; i += 1){
        randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * countryCollection[listNum-1].length);
        randomizedList.push(countryCollection[listNum-1][randNum]);
        countryCollection[listNum-1].splice(randNum, 1);
    }
    console.log(randomizedList);
    writeRow(randomizedList);
}

function writeRow(randomizedList){
    var row = document.createElement('tr'),
        cell;

    randomizedList.forEach(function(ele){
        cell = document.createElement('td');
        cell.innerHTML = ele;
        row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    console.log(row);
    document.getElementById('myTable').appendChild(row);
}
```

Comment: That still leaves some columns as undefined.

Comment: Make a fiddle, there are several problems with your code.  It helps us if you narrow down which one of the problems you need help with.

Comment: Ok, in the process of doing that now.

Comment: "document.write is disallowed in JSFiddle environment and might break your fiddle." This might explain why I can't seem to load my JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/m5WF7/